# Getting pixel color at location with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm drawing a bunch of rectangles to the siaply screen, and I'm wondering how I would go about reading the rgb color at a certain pixel location? For example, I want to get the color of the pixel at location 0,0 on the display screen, and it return the value [0,0,0] (or similar).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_at

`Surface.get_at((x, y)): return Color`

> Return a copy of the RGBA Color
>   value at the given pixel. If the Surface has no per pixel alpha, then
>   the alpha value will always be 255 (opaque). If the pixel position is
>   outside the area of the Surface an IndexError exception will be
>   raised.

Comment: I tried something similar but couldn't quite get it. This was a simpler and functional way. Thanks.

Comment: If there a way to return the color without the alpha value?

Comment: @TrumpetDude `Surface.get_at((x, y))[:3]` will get the first 3 values thus removing the alpha value