# How to create a delete function for deleting squares in pygame

Tags: pygame

I am trying to implement the diamond dash game using pygame. To be more specific, when you clicking with mouse on 3 squares with same colour in a row or column, then these squares must deleted and after new squares must take their position, randomly. My program can find the specific coordinates of a square but i am struggle on how to delete those specific squares.

Can you help me please? thank you.

```
import random, time, pygame, sys, copy

from pygame.locals import *

black    = (   0,   0,   0)
white    = ( 255, 255, 255)
green    = (   0, 255,   0)
red      = ( 255,   0,   0)
size = [700, 485]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)



# This sets the width and height of each grid location
width  = 64
height = 64

# This sets the margin between each cell
margin = 5

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimesional
# array is simply a list of lists.
grid = []
for row in range(7):
# Add an empty array that will hold each cell
# in this row
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(80):
        grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell

imgnum = 7
imglist = []
for i in range(1, imgnum+1):
    dimge = pygame.image.load('imge%s.png' % i)
    imglist.append(dimge)



grid[1][5] = 1

pygame.init()


pygame.display.set_caption("dimond dash")

done = False

for row in range(7):
  for column in range(8):
      screen.blit(random.choice(imglist), [(margin+width)*column+margin,
             (margin+height)*row+margin,
                          width,
                          height])    



while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = pos[0] // (width + margin)
            row = pos[1] // (height + margin)
            grid[row][column] = 1
            print("Click ", pos, "Grid coordinates: ", row, column)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Just fyi you can reduce your grid initialization to `grid = [[0]*80]*7` ;) You don't need those loops.

Comment: I am getting the position with pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos(). The result is like: ('Click ', (538, 441), 'Grid coordinates: ', 6, 7). I am stuck on getting that position and say "if exists square with same colour in position next to this (e.g. 538, 441) then delete all the squares with the same colour.

Comment: Ohh oops, sorry, I misinterpreted your code. :) I was in C++ mode for a second so my mind just ignored everything after the `//` LOL. Anyways why not store the click coordinates in a list? Then you can have a function which tests to see if any 3 coordinates in that list are 3 in a row or 3 in a column.

Comment: [(237, 96), (247, 188), (245, 221), (165, 272), (292, 308), (278, 375), (382, 361)]! this is the list with the positions on mouse clicking.Noone element of this list has the same position. So, i want to delete elements with the same colour. That means that the position of those elements for me are not helpful. i have to find something with the colour i think ! :S

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of a data structure to store which cells will be deleted.
You can try this:

> 1. Generate your grid.
> 2. For each cell that is not in a group:
>
>    i. create a new group
>
>    ii. get the color of the cell
>
>    iii. if any of the neighbors have the same color, repeat the algorithm, but add the new cell to the group.
> 3. At the end you will have groups of cells.

Now when a player clicks on a cell, you look up the group list, and find the group that has been clicked. Don't know the rules, but here you can check if the group is big enough, or simply generate new cells in their places.
Now for each new cell, do a similar algorithm:

> 1. Check all neighbors - There are two possibilities.
>    i. If only one neighbor is the same color, add the new color to the neighbors
>    group.
>    ii. If there are more, check if they both are in the same
>    group, if so, add this cell, if not, you need to merge both groups and
>    add the cell.

EDIT:

There are 2 possibilities for getting the color

1. you images are one color - you can get the color at a point:
   [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215803/getting-pixel-color-at-location-with-pygame)
2. If you store your cells as sprites and checking the sprite image would tell you if they are the same color.

Actually now that I see it, your bliting loop makes you lose information about the cells.
It would be better if you store the results of random choice, and then blit them. This way you will know which cell is which.

Comment: I've got an issue here! i am using images(its images of squares). imgnum = 7
imglist = []
for i in range(1, imgnum+1):
    dimge = pygame.image.load('imge%s.png' % i)
    imglist.append(dimge)

So, i can't have access to the colour of the image! right?